# Shall I require $f$ to be "Borel measurable" or "Lebesgue measurable"?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

This may not really be a mathematical question...
Suppose I have a probability measure $p$ on the Borel sets of $X$. When I calculate $\int_X fdp$ (defined as Lebesgue integral), shall I require $f$ to be "Borel measurable" or "Lebesgue measurable"? The reason for the former is obvious. But I cannot immediately rule out the latter because I have a feeling that "Lebesgue integral" corresponds to "Lebesgue measurable"...Or maybe "Lebesgue integral" is just a term that distinguishes itself from "Riemann integral", so even if $\int_X fdp$ is a Lebesgue integral, $f$ does not have to be Lebesgue measurable?

p.s. Borel sets should be a subset of Leabesgue measurable sets on $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour ,

C est une question intéressante .Un espace mesurable est un ensemble E muni d une tribu T. Ensuite on peut définir une mesure positive  m sur un espace mesurable (E,T) . Par exemple on peut prendre pour E un espace topologique et prendre pour T la tribu borélienne (c'est la tribu engendrée par les ouverts de E ) .
On peut en particulier prendre E = R , avec T = la tribu borélienne . Et l on peut prendre pour m la mesure borélienne donnée par m(]a,b[) = b-a  . On peut alors compléter la tribu borélienne en lui ajoutant les ensembles qui sont de mesure nulle  pour m mais qui ne sont pas boréliens . On obtient une tribu T* ( la tribu de Lebesgue )   et on prolonge naturellement la mesure m en une mesure m* . On peut ensuite définir l'intégrale de Lebesgue pour les fonctions  Lebesgue mesurables ( au sens de la tribu T*) plutôt que pour les fonctions Borel mesurables (au sens de la tribu T ) . Cela rend les théorèmes plus simples à énoncer et plus facile à démontrer